# Does Next-Auth allow for users who sign in through socials to get a unique username?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

While I would like to implement both a regular username and password sign in, I would also like to allow users to signup/signin with a social account like Google.

I am planning on using NextAuth

If they sign up with Google, is there a way to make them add a unique username and have it tied in with NextAuth?

My app would require users to have unique usernames for profile reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ability to directly connect a username to the GoogleProvider in NextAuth.

You should store your account information in your database as generic accounts. Subsequently, the user would have the ability to specify a username no matter how they signed in. For example a pseudo database may look like:

```
User Database
     - Accounts
               - <ID>
                     - username: "x"
                     -{"SignInProvider": "GoogleProvider", "clientId": "x", "clientSecret": "x"}
```

Comment: Right, so I am aware NextAuth allows for providers to connect the data to MongoDB. So what you are claiming is that I am basically out of luck with this feature? Users would need to have unique usernames.  Or what you are saying is regardless how they sign in, after signing in they could be redirected to a page that requires them to create a username, and this username is what i would use to reference them across the app?

Comment: Yes, the latter would be the most reliable bet (and the way I have previously done it)

Comment: To expand on this: esentially the "accounts" I have in my databasr that store the googleprovider data after google sign in, would be where i store all the other data for my user? It would esentially be how i reference the user here on out?

Comment: You could do it that way, or create a separate database where each user is specified by their individual UUID. When a user signs in regardless of provider, Google, email etc., you should be able to get this UUID. In that other database, find the table associated with that UUID and pull all of the data in their account, including the username.

Comment: This is very very interesting. Thank you for this back and forth. I am assuming also I could use their email from the session after they login, to reference another database where their username and all their data exists? That database would have their data, username, and email inside to reference

Comment: Correct! If this solved your problem I recommend accepting the answer so other people looking up the question know it was solved